# change wordpress label - published

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to change label of published in posts list, please check attached file [image]

I have used this array for changing other labels, those are working fine i want to know what is key for published label
$message['labels'] = array(
                'name'               => __( 'Reminders'                    ),
                'title'              => __( 'TitleReminders'  ),

Answer (score 0):

cant you just go into the language file and change Published to whatever you want to change it to ?. If you cant find it, I use this program which is really useful for that, you would just type in Published as the word to find and point it to your wordpress install (this needs to be on your pc), hit search and it will look through all the files finishing any instances of Published and lists the files and lines it is on.

http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=agent%20ransack&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDQQjBAwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmythicsoft.com%2Fpage.aspx%3Fpage%3Ddownload%26type%3Dagentransack&ei=iJUeT-zSGsXBhAf9q-TuDQ&usg=AFQjCNHTGp5dkwsjUU0SFdgDaHeVxlZZ7Q&sig2=GLJnsIc1Do9chMXkedE6vA

Comment: Actually i dont want to change it on whole site, i want to change it on my plugin which is using posts setup to show reminders.